# Does an infinite matrix exist with each row converging to 0 and each column to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Is there an infinite matrix $A_{mn}$  such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }A_{mn}=0 $ for every $m$ and $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty }A_{mn}=1 $ for every $n$ ?

Any clue as to how to start on this?

Comment: P.S: my latex tends to begin in a new line after the text whenever i inser $$ , any idea as to how to avoid that?

Comment: Just use a single $ instead.

Comment: @Bhargav: That's what LaTeX *always* does. For in-line formulas, use a single `$`.

Comment: @Bhargav: This isn't so much about an infinite matrix as it is about an infinite series with double indices. The fact that it's a matrix is irrelevant. Just take $A_{mn} = \frac{m}{m+n}$.

Comment: Ya now i get it , rather than looking at it fromt he point of a matrix question ,i should have seen t as a calculus quetsion then the problem would have been solved. Thx arturo and zev

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $A_{mn}=\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^n$? We get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_{mn}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^n=0$$
because $0<\frac{m}{m+1}<1$ for all $m\geq 1$, and
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}A_{mn}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^n=\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^n=1^n=1.$$

Answer (score 20):

Another example:

- $A_{mn}=0$ if $m<n$,
- $A_{mn}=1$ if $m\geq n$.

Comment: wow, you don't even have to know much about limits for this!

Comment: Exercise for the OP: you can even modify Jonas's answer to get a yet different limit for all "diagonals", that is, $\lim_{m \to \infty} A_{m,m+k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} A_{n+k,n} = \frac12$ for $k\geq 0$

Comment: @Willie: Nice exercise! (I had to fight my urge to post a solution.)